# How do I close the loop on batched writes in AWS?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs

I have an endpoint in my api that supports writes.  The resource in question is collaborative, so it is reasonable to expect that there will be parallel write requests arriving concurrently.

If the number of writes is small, then this is relatively straight forward to do with a simple lambda - read the current state, compute the new state, compare and swap, spin until the swap succeeds or until we give up.  In either case, we compute the appropriate http response and return it to the caller.

If the API is successful, then eventually the waste of conflicting writes becomes expensive enough to address.

It looks as though the natural response is to copy the requests into a queue, with a function that consumes batches; within each batch, we process the requests in sequence, storing the new write, and computing the appropriate response to the request.

What are the options for getting those computed responses copied into the http responses, and what are the trade offs to be be considered?

My sense is that in handling the http request, after (synchronously) enqueue the message, I need to block/poll on *something* that will eventually be populated with the response to the request.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will count an an answer, but I do not agree that the natural response is to copy/queue/block; that feels like you're just trading optimistic concurrency control for a kind of pessimistic one (and you'd probably have an easier time just implementing a lock using e.g. Redis - not to mention there are other issues with Lambda itself that would make the approach you describe even more difficult).

Users probably do not want an API like this as it would have high latency.

In my opinion an API that is well designed for collaborate modification of some shared state has higher order constructs that make the API successful: thinking of a conversation as an example, you would decompose the chat in to individual messages, where each message is in reply to some other message; the concurrent modification to the conversation is append-only for the most part (you might allow a user to edit an individual message but that's not a point of resource contention) and you might do things like count the number of messages within the conversation asynchronously such that it is eventually consistent.

You can look at the domain of your API and see if there's a way to expose modification to it in such a way that reduces contention by making modifications target sub-entities (even if the API represents this as a single resource, the storage engine does not have to).

Another option is looking in to a model like event sourcing, where the changes themselves are literally appended and you derive the state from some snapshot plus recent changes.